# How does remember me differ from session timeout

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies

I have built an app in CakePHP that allows a user to login and do some stuff, it keeps the user logged in for about 24 hours I think by default. And this is handled by a session/cookie as a cookie also gets created...

1.) So what would a remember me bring to the party? As all that would do is create ANOTHER cookie that sets a timeout and keeps the user logged in... But this functionality exists in every single app by default with the session right? But I've seen lots of sites doing this but I don't get why as the session is doing this out of the box :/

2.) Also how come sessions expire even if a user continues to use a website? e.g. if I set it to be 1 minute but refresh every 30 seconds it will still expire... but I kept the site active before it could expire so how could it still did expire? This is annoying as I have a expiration for an app of 1 hour but even when the client is using the site it expires after 1 hour regardless of activity.

Would be great if someone could answer these 2 questions.

**UPDATE: I've created a bounty on this in the hope of getting a CakePHP expert to help fix this problem. The issue is that the Sessions expire after the timeout REGARDLESS of user interaction. What I want to do is say I have a session lasting 5 minutes, and the user causes a postback every 30 seconds, then that session will still be around after the 5 minutes. This is not the case at the moment...**

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'start' => true,
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => 1,
        'cookieTimeout' => 1,
        'autoRegenerate' => true
    ));
```

Comment: Can you include your session configuration?  There's a lot of things that could be happening here, and that's a good starting point.

Comment: Added the config and set the time to be very low so I can test the theory!

Comment: Once you understand the difference note that Zend Framework uses the session cookie to implement remember me - apparently they need to tune into threads like this!

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to request changes to a framework - it's for questions that can be answered.  Post your suggestion here: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard for changes to CakePHP.

Comment: I'll get back to you on this :-)

Answer (score 9):

OK, let's see if I can grab some of that bounty (booty?), while also testing my explanatory skills :)

So let's start with #1.

> So what would a remember me bring to the party?

What's important to distinguish here is the difference between a "session cookie" and a "remember me cookie".

Since HTTP is a [stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), a session cookie is used to tie several requests to a single user. Without it, every single request to your webserver is completely unrelated to every other request. Can you imagine writing applications without sessions? Every request is completely empty, no logins, no session variables..every request is an unknown user! This basically means *no web applications*!

Now, important thing here is to realise that you **absolutely don't want** your session to last 24 hours! In my book, this is a very big no-no. The shorter your session is, the safer it is (at least theoretically). Why? Because a [session can be hijacked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)! The longer your session is around, the more chance it has of being hijacked.

For example, imagine a banking application. Also, imagine your user is accessing it on a public PC (our user is not the brightest). So he's managing his account or whatever..and his phone rings. Being an idiot, he takes the call and leaves, without logging out. Do you want your session to expire in 5 minutes, 15 minutes, or 24 hours? Don't know about you, but for something as critical as online banking, I want that session gone ASAP.

Moving on to the "remember me" part.

So session cookie "connects" multiple requests in a single session, what does the "remember me" cookie do? In simple terms: it ties multiple *sessions* to a single user.

You want your site to be easy and pleasant to use, and logging in is almost never pleasant. It's just an annoying thing you have to do every time before doing that thing you really want to do. A remember me cookie removes that annoyance.

You log in once, check the box, and now you're always logged in *on that PC*. This is why you should **never** use "remember me" feature while on a shared PC, because the next person will have your identity. *Legitimately*. This is why remember me cookies are also a security risk, they can be hijacked much like the session cookie.

Finally, there is one crucial difference between a session cookie and a remember me cookie: [expiration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age). Session cookies normally expire when you close your browser (or after a time you've specified explicitly), whereas remember me cookies typically last for much longer.

> Also how come sessions expire even if a user continues to use a
>   website?

To make it simple, *they don't*. You must have changed the way cake (or your application) handles sessions. The answer must be somewhere in your code. The reason why you didn't get a satisfactory answer here is because we can't see your code. You'll just have to debug and track what happens to your cookies. JB Nizet gave you some suggestions.

One thing I know that may cause trouble on some servers is cake's security level. Try lowering it in your `/Config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium'); // or 'low'
```

If that doesn't help, then the answer is definitely in your code. I hope this answer will push you in the right direction!

Comment: What I don't get: Doesn't the "remember me" cookie have the same problem and can be hijacked? For the sake of security we keep sessions short lasting and then we introduce another cookie with exact that problem? To me that sounds like encrypting a password with another password which is publicly available.

Answer (score 8):

1. What it would bring is that if the user closes its browser and restarts it, it would still log in automatically. This is not the case with a session cookie, since such a cookie is deleted as soon as the browser is closed.
2. Maybe the page you went to every 30 seconds didn't start the session. In that case, the session mechanism is not used, and the expiration date of the session is not reset to `now + 1 minute`. Or maybe the refresh only hits the browser cache, and not the server.

Comment: 1.) When you say close the browser, do you mean actually quit the application as when I close the window and then revisit the website I am still logged in. 2.) How do I fix this? I'm using CakePHP and as long as the user is using the site e.g. loading a page etc then the session should not be expiring unless inactive for that 1 hour.

Comment: 1) No, I mean "close the browser", i.e. close all the browser windows. 2) make sure to call session_start() on every page of the application, even if the session is not used by that page.

Comment: What about CakePHP world? I was under the impression that sessions exist across the app?

Comment: I don't know anythging about CakePHP, sorry.

Comment: @Cameron the session should persist based on the settings you have in `/Config/core.php`. If it isn't, something else is happening (i.e., accessing unauthorized location and therefore logged out, etc).

Comment: @jeremyharris Not accessing anything unauthorized! If I login and then view the normal homepage it will show me as logged in and if I keep refreshing the page it will then expire after the timeout regardless of me interacting with the website...

Comment: Tried: `'autoRegenerate' => true` in the config but Cake still drops the session after the timeout regardless of using the application WITHIN the time period. e.g. refreshing every 10 seconds within a 2 minute timeout should mean it would never expire but it does!

Comment: Perhaps your server isn't writing the session correctly. As I said, it sounds like something else is happening. There are multiple variables, you'll have to do some research on your server. Make sure to turn on debug, it might give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

1.) The difference between a session cookie and "remember me" is that a session cookie has an expiration date of "0". Which means "expire when the browser closes". Whereas "remember me" gives a specific expiration date, say a month from now, to that same session cookie. That's the only difference. You might think this difference in functionality is trivial or meaningless, but consider this: at home I don't want to bother logging in every evening to the same damn Yahoo! account, whereas at work I don't want to bother deleting my cookies every time I have to go take a pee.

2.) Session cookies should not expire even when the application is being used. Where and under what circumstances are you seeing this behavior? It is wrong.

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour everywhere on the app. The session expires after the timeout even though I am navigating through pages etc.

Answer (score 1):

Understand the combination of the security settings combined with the timeouts, that's a very important part. When security is set at a high level sessions might be killed before you expect.

Next to that test with the internal cake session store. That way the local system configuration cannot influence it. It might be that PHP settings override the settings in Cake. So set the session store to Cake. That will create a directory with sessions which you can control.

Likewise it is a combination of server settings and expecting the config of Cake does override these server settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I do this:

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
        'start' => true,
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'timeout' => 1,
        'cookieTimeout' => 1,
        'autoRegenerate' => true
    ));

/**
 * The level of CakePHP security.
 */
    Configure::write('Security.level', 'high');
```

It fixes the issue! So the session last 10 seconds, but If I refresh every 2-3 seconds then I will still be logged in after 10 seconds as the cookie is being refreshed. So it seems that the PHP settings of my hosting environment are/were causing the expiring session/cookie... Why would this happen though?

Comment: Because of what I have written in my answer, you changed the cookie storage. That stops the influence of PHP and server settings on the sessions.

Comment: Not sure who marked my answer down? Also noticed that `'autoRegenerate' => true` causes it to break so had to remove that as well!

Comment: There are a few bugs in cakephp 2.1 regading this subject. I have the same problem with a auto refresh function that uses ajax. This also should keep the session alive and it doens't. Very annoying. I have to look back at the work I've done on this subject.
If you take a look at the local and master value of the session settings in phpinfo() you'll notice some inconsistencies with the cakephp settings. This makes debugging difficult and the sollution involves modifiying cakephp source code. Which I don't recommend doing because the obvious problems with upgrades later on.